# Referencing the document scope from a Javascript Event Handler

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple event handler (change) on a form control (input type-number) and I want to do some work based on the value entered.  This works great with use of the 'this' keyword.

I'm running into a scope problem when I try to *also* check the value of another control (another input type-number).  I understand this is a scope issue but I just can't figure out how to reference the second control from the event handler of the first.

So for instance;

```
if (this.value) != "" { do something }
```

Works great, but;

```
if (this.value != "" && document.getElementById("someothercontrol").value) != "") { do something else }
```

Fails.  As I indicated, I realize this document object is out of scope, but I don't know the syntax to reference it (I presume there is a way).

Comment: You're missing parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the reference to the input element at a higher scope, here is an example:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
const input2 = document.getElementById('input2');

for (let input of inputs) {
  
  input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    
    console.log(input1.value);
    console.log(input2.value);
    
  })
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" type="text">
<br>
<input id="input2" type="text">
```

If you don't want the variables to be at global scope you can put it in an immediately invoked function expression:

```
(() => {
   // your scoped code here
})()
```